# iOS animationWithDuration chaining first animation isn't showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, animatewithduration

I have 2 animations with one calling the other, but only the later is actually happening. I am not sure with the issue is. I am new to iOS. I am trying to animate it up then down but only the down is happening.

Also, if I change the call from `[self animateUp]` to `[self animateDown]`, no animation happens.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.logoView = ({
        UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thisImage"];
        imageView;
    })];
    [self animateUp];
}

- (void)animateUp
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.logoView.frame.origin.x, self.logoView.frame.origin.y - 40, self.logoView.frame.size.width, self.logoView.frame.size.height);
        self.logoView.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self animateDown];
    }];
}

- (void)animateDown
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.logoView.frame.origin.x, self.logoView.frame.origin.y + 40, self.logoView.frame.size.width, self.logoView.frame.size.height);
    self.logoView.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:nil ];
}
```

Comment: can you show the other codes where you call `animateUp`?

Comment: Your code works for me, may you are calling animateUp method in bad way.

Comment: I only call it here, and I've added the declaration of logoView.

Comment: @user3338275 how is  the frame set for the logoView? do you use constraints?

Comment: There are no constraints for this.

Comment: what happens if you move the call to animateUp from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear?

Comment: What happens is it works! Thanks CSmith! If yo uwant to add as an answer, I'll up it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `animateUp` is occurring before the ImageView has an initial frame set.  You can defer this to `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and should see the animations occur correctly.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.logoView = ({
        UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thisImage"];
        imageView;
    })];
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self animateUp];    // at this point the ImageView has its frame set
}
```

Please be aware that viewDidAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews could get called multiple times in the lifetime of your UIViewController, so you'll want to accomodate for this should you only want the animation to occur once.

Comment: If I want it once, would a dispatch_once be sufficient?

Comment: dispatch_once will do it, but the view wouldn't animate again should this view controller go away and be re-instantiated